# How can I use a localized string from GlobalMaterialLocalizations?

Tags: flutter, localization, material-design, flutter-layout

I want to use one of the predefined localized strings available in the [GlobalMaterialLocalizations class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html). I have added the necessary bits and pieces to my `MaterialApp`

```
MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
        const LocalizationDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''),
        const Locale('sv', ''),
    ],
    localeResolutionCallback:(Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
         return locale; // Return a different locale if the user choose another language in the settings
    },

    ...
```

and my custom `LocalizationDelegate` is working fine. I just can't figure out how to use the predefined strings in `GlobalMaterialLocalizations`, since there is no `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.of(BuildContext)` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was looking for the `.of(BuildContext)` method in the wrong class. To actually use the strings, the `MaterialLocalizations` class should be used.

```
Text( MaterialLocalizations.of(context).okButtonLabel )
```

Hope it might help someone else struggling with the same problem.